# Capture dual pictures with iPhone 7Plus and AVCaptureSession

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I am working on this piece of swift 3 code:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,                        position: .back)

let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)

if captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)
{
    captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
}
```

Then, i take a picture with an AVCapturePhotoOutput object and i get the picture in AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate object.

It works fine.
What i want to do is to take a picture with the iPhone 7 Plus dual camera. I want to get 2 pictures, like the official iOS camera app:
- One picture with background blur
- A second picture, without blur

Do you think it is possible ?

Thanks